# Git ignore is not ignoring folder **META-INF**

Tags: java, git

i'm using git with source tree app i want to ignore the contents of the folder file **META-INF** like the file **persistence.xml**

```
workspace\Data\src\META-INF\persistence.xml
```

i put the path in **.gitignore** file

```
#Ignore META-INF 
*/*/src/META-INF/*
```

but the file not ignored by git  , how to ignore all files in this folder **META-INF**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the files are already being tracked by Git, you must do the following:

1. Fix .gitignore so it is ignoring the META-INF folder

   ```
   */META-INF/*
   ```
2. Remove the files that should have originally been ignored

   ```
   git rm --cached -r
   git add .
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Just write:

```
#Ignore META-INF 
META-INF
```

this doesn't work for you?

Comment: doesn't work  
my _.gitignore_ file contain other folder and work correctly so why this folder doesn't ignored

Comment: are the problem related to the name of the folder **META-INF **

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
Data/src/META-INF/
```

Also in case you already indexed some xmls, you have to clear it from the index.

```
git rm --cached <file>
```